# Getting null value onDelete() in Firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am getting null value in onDelete() firebase cloud function. Below is my code

```
 exports.jobSeekerToES=functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}/userFileDetails/files/{fileKey}').onDelete(event=>
{

var file=event.data.val();
console.log("deleted file key"+event.params.fileKey);
console.log("deleted file "+file);  // file is null

});
```

it prints fileKey on logs. But file is null 
Please help me where i am wrong

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`event.data.val()` returns the value of the location *after* the deletion. For an `onDelete()` trigger, it will alway be null.  To get the value before the deletion use the [previous](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#previous) property of the event snapshot:

```
exports.jobSeekerToES=functions.database.ref(
    '/Users/{userId}/userFileDetails/files/{fileKey}').onDelete(event=>
{

  var file=event.data.previous.val();  // <= CHANGED
  console.log("deleted file key"+event.params.fileKey);
  console.log("deleted file "+file);

});
```

Comment: Thnx @Bob Synder

Comment: Really helpful post!

Comment: is there any way to do this with v1? We get snapshots now instead of events.

Comment: The link is broken now